# how to add editor in woocomerce product category section

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

site is simple woocomerce site i am new developer in wordpress can anyone guide me on one query?
   i need the editor into the product category section anyone has the idea how i can do that with plugin or custom code.
**please see the screenshot where i want the editor.**

[image]

i have tried http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/display-the-full-tinymce-editor-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i get the solution it is very simple you can install the "Rich text".

here is the url 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/rich-text-tags/